# Add new line to /etc/sudoers via ansible

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, ansible

I am trying to add new line to the `/etc/sudoers`file via ansible.
But it does not work what is the problem, Could you please help?

I have tried `visudo -c` command in order to make `sudoers` file to writeable.

Except from

```
sudo echo "test ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

all the lines work.

These are sh files I executed, none of them worked.

```
 sudo adduser test
 sudo echo "******" | passwd --stdin test
 sudo cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers_20180418
 sudo echo "test ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
 sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config20180418
 sudo sed -i 's/AllowUsers/AllowUsers test/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

.sh file

```
 sudo adduser test
 sudo echo "******" | passwd --stdin test
 sudo cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers_20180418
 visudo -c
 sudo echo "test ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
 sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config20180418
 sudo sed -i 's/AllowUsers/AllowUsers test/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Does RHEL have `/etc/sudoers.d`? If so consider adding a file snippet in there, instead of editing `/etc/sudoers` itself.

Comment: Doesn't ansible run as root? If so, using `sudo` is pointless and unnecessary.

Comment: When you write "_none of them worked_", what happened? Error messages? Files updated incorrectly? Please clarify.

Comment: actually that is the problem I just looked at the ansible logs and it says only root can execute sudoers file but the thing is ansible user have root permission and I added sudo su - command to the .sh files but it hanged

Comment: Since ansible already had root there is no point whatsoever using `sudo` (or `su`). You're also using them wrongly. I strongly suggest you remove them from your scripts.

Comment: yes I removed it, just tried it.

Comment: And...........?

Comment: Ansible has some preferences to edit sudoers file I will try it

Comment: if it would not help, I will try to add new file to the /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: I tried your solution it works thank you @roaima

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ansible to run a script you've written by hand to affect changes, instead of invoking the ansible modules that will accomplish these tasks specifically? Why introduce the need to troubleshoot a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the command line

```
sudo echo "test ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

will redirect the output of the `sudo` command, using the identity of the original user to perform the redirection - and since you need root access in order to write to `/etc/sudoers`, this will fail. The `echo` command runs as root, but it does not do the redirection - this was already set up by the shell that was preparing the `sudo echo ...` command line for execution. And since you're using sudo here, I suspect that shell was not running as root.

You could rephrase this as:

```
echo "test ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers >/dev/null
```

In this version:

- the `echo` command is executed as the original user
- the redirection to /dev/null is executed as the original user
- but `tee -a <filename>` appends a copy of the piped input to the specified file as root, which is exactly what you need to happen.

Comment: We've ascertained that the script runs as root.

Comment: The echo command perhaps, but not necessarily the redirection. See my edit above.

Comment: No: the script runs as root. So the `sudo` is unnecessary. Which unfortunately means your (otherwise correct) fix is also unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, After I remove `sudo` command begining of the statement it worked.

Comment: `echo "test ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers`

Comment: OK, good. Nevertheless, I hope my answer may help someone else whose problem is similar but not exactly identical.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL has the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory, the files in which are included as part of `/etc/sudoers`. Consider adding a file snippet in there, instead of editing `/etc/sudoers` itself:

```
echo "test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
```

Alternatively, you may find that Ansible has facilities for managing `sudoers` directly.